# facebook share button with url containing querystring

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Let's say I have a `Event.aspx` page which displays the event depending upon the query string which has the `EventId`. I want to have a Facebook share button on that page such that I don't have to specify the URL.The problem with specifying URL is that it keeps changing(`EventId` keeps changing) and so I wish i could just fetch the URL from the address bar or something to share on Facebook that particular Event.

My link would something like :

> http://www.mywebsite.com/Events.aspx?EventId=3

Again, the `EventId` keeps changing and I want to share that link on Facebook for the current `EventId`.

Comment: If you have the value `3` in your script already (because you use it to fetch the content for the event with that id) – then where is the problem with outputting the correct value for the URL attribute of the share button dynamically …?

Comment: Update the url you are sharing at the same time as you update the url?